# Trying an ActiveRecord .create on a concurrent ruby thread is not persisting

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

This is a very interesting problem and I have no idea why this is happening...

I have a class similar to:

```
require 'concurrent'

class DuplicationCheck
  include Concurrent::Async

  def check_duplication(params)
    # Time intensive check
    
    Duplication.create(params)  # This create does not insert into the DB when run Async!
  end
end
```

So the call below works fine and the duplication returns with an id:

`DuplicationCheck.new.check_duplication(params)`

The call below does not work as I would expect, it runs asynchronously which is great, but doesn't insert the Duplication record into the database.

`DuplicationCheck.new.async.check_duplication(params)`

There's no errors, but after debugging it looks like ActiveRecord is creating an object in memory but not persisting...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: ``.create()`` always returns an object, even if it fails to create a record (e.g., it fails validation). If you change it to ``.create!`` do you get an exception in the async case?

Comment: Good point @rmlockerd, let me try and see.